# Custom Members and role database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

Newbie here, I havn't done much membership stuff for asp.net. I am trying to take advantage of the asp.net membership mechanism for a new app I am building, but I wish to store the member information in my own database. what are my options? Do I need to write a custom membership provider? or does asp.net have a standard provider for sql (with specified tables and column names)?

Quick edit: Each member is logged in using their windows authentication, but I also need to store extra information about them such as their department, age, rank etc.

Comment: Why do you need to customize the table and column names?  You can store membership in a separate database from your application's database, and if you need different layouts of the data, use views.

Comment: This post will get you started with creating a membership database from scratch OR adding the schema to an existing database:  http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx

Comment: this is a bug tracker database, and the majority of the tables in the app's database rely on userID, so i wish to store the user info in the same database and link them together using foreign keys

Comment: @NickBork Does asp.net default membership db support windows authentication? I wish to know who is using my app without using a seperate login for them, they will be authenticated via windows.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using new [Universal Membership Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)

Membership Provider is a steep learning curve. If you are not familiar with Membership Provider, please use the default one rather than implementing custom membership provider.

Then use the UserId of User table as primary key in other tables which you store user related information.

[image]