# membership & profile help needed using createuserwizard and login control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, login-control, createuserwizard

I am working on a project where I got a task to create a user (using the CreateUserWizard control). I have to save the user in a specific table in the SQL Server database.

Also create a login (using the Login control) and after the login is authenticated it should hold the profile information.

So far, I have created  CustomProfile that inherites the ProfileBase. Also have created 3 aspx pages.

1. Login.aspx
2. CreateUser.aspx
3. Default.aspx

My CustomProfile looks like the following:

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    static public UserProfile CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return (UserProfile)(ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName));
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return (string)base["FirstName"]; }
        set { base["FirstName"] = value; Save(); }
    }


    public string LastName
    {
        get { return (string)base["LastName"]; }
        set { base["LastName"] = value; Save(); }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return (DateTime)base["DateOfBirth"]; }
        set { base["DateOfBirth"] = value; Save(); }
    }

    public ContactInfo Contact
    {
        get { return (ContactInfo)base["Contact"]; }
        set { base["Contact"] = value; Save(); }
    }
}
```

I have used `aspnet_regsql.exe` and it created multiple tables in the sql server and storing the data in those tables and is working fine. I would like to save the information into my table eg. `tblUserInfo`. How should I proceed? I checked multiple forums but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's nice.  You might get more results if you actually asked a question though.

Comment: @MystereMan: I am very new to asp .net and not sure what would be a good question in this situation. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all aspnet_regsql.exe is outdated. You might want to consider using [ASP.Net Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

I assume your question is ***save the information into my table eg. tblUserInfo***

Instead of using CreateUserWizard, you can collect the user information and save it by yourself.

[1. Creating a tblUserInfo table (alternative solution to ASP.Net Profile)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114307/296861)

[2. Inserting UserInfo into tblUserInfo after creating a user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10403299/296861)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="Server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="Server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="Server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordQuestionTextBox" runat="Server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordAnswerTextBox" runat="Server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="Server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="Server" /> 

string username = UsernameTextBox;  
string password = PasswordTextBox.text; 
string email = EmailTextBox.text; 
string passwordQuestion = PasswordQuestionTextBox.text; 
string passwordAnswer = PasswordAnswerTextBox.text; 
bool isApproved = true; 

MembershipCreateStatus status; 

MembershipUser membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(
username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, out status); 

if (status != MembershipCreateStatus.Success) 
   throw new Exception(status.ToString()); 

// Save the rest of the user info to tblUserInfo with userId
Guid userId = (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

[3. How to make UserInfo available for login user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114451/can-you-wrap-the-roleprincipal-in-a-custom-iprincipal-object/10116939#10116939)

Comment: Thanks mate. Looks like the solution I was looking for.